# Jquery array filtering - grep()?

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array as the one shown below with jquery's own functions? I assume that grep() is the one that I should be looking at?

Thanks!

The array:

```
array (

    array(
        'id' => 0,
        'name' => 'myName',
        'weight' => 100  
    );

    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'myName2',
        'weight' => 150,
    );

);
```

**Edit:** It's a PHP array to clarify things - im not completely sure how to write a proper javascript (JSON?) array?

Comment: Well, yeah. It's a PHP array that's not yet converted to JSON for illustrative purposes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Sort or filter? Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: Hmm. I want to filter it like a "MYSQL GET WHERE" query sort of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume that you're actually talking about a Javascript array that looks something like this:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'myName',
        weight: 100
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'myName2',
        weight: 150
    }
]
```

You can then call the native Javascript function `sort()` on this array.  In this case, you'll need to provide a function callback.  This needs to be defined with the syntax `function (a, b)`.  `a` and `b` are the elements in your array.  You need to return `-1` if `a` should be higher ranked than `b` in the array, `1` if it should be lower ranked and `0` if they are equal.

If you want to sort them in descending order of weight, you could do the following:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.weight - a.weight;
});
```

Comment: It might also be better/cheaper to deliver this array already sorted from the server, especially if the sort is complex.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such method as to sort an array with jQuery. Why don't you just use `Array.prototype.sort` instead? It's native code and you may pass it a function to compare any of the nested arrays' values.

```
var myarr = [
    {id: 3, foo: 'bax'},
    {id: 1, foo: 'baz'},
    {id: 2, foo: 'bay'}
];

// Sort by id
myarr = myarr.sort(function(x, y) {
    return x.id >= y.id;
});
```